# How to get batch to run a python script on windows 8

Tags: batch-file, python-3.x, windows-8.1

I have created a python script that I would like to run every time I start my computer.
So I started creating a batch file that could later be put into my startup folder.
I tried this:
@echo off
start "C:\Users..........." (I gave the exact path)
and when I run it you can see the python script pop up for a moment, but then shuts down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a batch file instead of running the .py script directly? Is it that you need the cmd shell to run in the same console after Python exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works here:

```
@echo off
start /b "" "%ProgramFiles%\Python33\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Test.py" "more parameters"
pause
```

Comment: AFAIK, most people don't have Python installed to `%ProgramFiles%`. Anyway the .py extension should be associated with py.exe in Python 3, so you just put a shebang at the top indicating the target Python version, e.g. `#!python3` and execute the script directly -- not as an argument of python.exe or py.exe.

Comment: @eryksun Many ways go to Rome. I do it my way. The Windows 64 bit standard folder for 64 bit applications is `%ProgramFiles%` and not `C:\\`, no matter what most people do.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the OP wants. If it's just to keep the console window open, a simple `input()` at the end of the script may suffice, but if modifying the script isn't desired then your solution using `start /b` followed by `pause` is good.

Comment: As to using pylauncher, I thought maybe you were unaware of it and would appreciate the tip; it's simpler to run `start /b "" "%UserProfile%\Test.py" "more parameters"` without having to worry about where Python is installed, or which version (2.x, 3.x -- 32-bit, 64-bit) a particular script requires.

Comment: @eryksun ok, it's always a good idea to have fewer parameters.